# Get email address inside System.Net.Mail.SendCompletedEventHandler

Tags: .net, email, callback, smtpclient

I have a method to send an email message to several email addresses. Something like this:

```
foreach(var email in emails){

    // code to create mail variable

    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(callBack);
    smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

And as expected, my callback is called one time for each email address. The callback pops a notification client side with the success/error message.

I wish to get the email address inside the callback, to be able to specify the success/error message with the email that has caused the success/error. **This is my callback as I wanted it to be, with the EMAIL variable**:

```
EmailSender.SendAsyncEmailDoneCallBack callBack = (sender, e) => {
    if (e.Cancelled)
        PushSystemNotification("Message canceled to " + EMAIL, CurrentUser);
    if (e.Error != null) 
        PushSystemNotification("Message not sent to " + EMAIL, CurrentUser);
    else
        PushSystemNotification("Message sent to " + EMAIL, CurrentUser);
};
```

**So, can anyone tell me if it is possible to get the email address from inside this send callback?** Or is there another way of doing this that can provide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the second argument of `SendAsync` (not `SendMailAsync`)

```
smtp.SendCompleted += (sndr, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine(e.UserState);
};
smtp.SendAsync(mail,"test");
```

it can be any object you want to pass to *SendCompleted* event handler.

Comment: The question was with regard to the SendMailAsync method and passing values to the callback handler; which, appears to remove the UserState pass through capability.